# PyCharm Erro Caractere Especial Trema

Tags: teclado, pycharm, mac, caracteres

Estou tendo um problema com o teclado ABNT do meu Mac ao utilizar o PyCharm (apenas com ele).

Ao digitar aspas simples (') ele apresenta um caractere especial (em quadrado e não reconhecido), o que atrapalha no momento de digitar.

Ao digitar aspas duplas (") há o mesmo efeito.

Descobri que o caractere especial é a trema (ä), mas o PyCharm reconhece de início. Seguem os prints de tela.

Preciso de uma solução dentro do PyCharm ou do próprio Mac. Obrigado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, a IDE está definida para UTF-8?

Comment: Bom dia, está sim.